# How to display text from current web address after submitting php form

Tags: php, html

How to display text from current web address after submitting form
www.example.com/?n=Example-Text

```
<form method="post" action="/submit.php">
    <div class="enter-name">
        <input class="animated pulse infinite" type="name" required="" maxlength="50" name="n" placeholder="Enter Your Text Here">
        <button class="btn" type="submit"><span>></span> Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the text from input `name="n"` ,
make the form method `GET` `<form method="get" action="/submit.php">`

and in your **submit.php**

```
<?php
echo $_GET['n'];
?>
```

Comment: he has a POST method in the form!

Comment: @DanieleFois read my complete answer... i mentioned it already

Comment: Thanks. but how i get the data also in url for eg. if i submit Example Text in field it render in url www.example.com/?n=Example-Text

Comment: @mkmobi if you change your post method to `get` , the data will render in the url.. so on your landing page you can `echo  $_GET['n'];`

Comment: yes, can you provide me the code without get, i m very thankful to you

Comment: If you want to display the text from URL , u should use get method ! @mkmobi You are welcome ! If my answer helped You, do accept it as correct answer !

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about a `GET` request when you code has a response that is a `POST` response as indicated in the form tag `<form method="post" action="/submit.php">`

For the example you gave, the **submit.php** page would need to have the following code

```
<?php echo $_POST['n']; ?>
```

This will display inline the value that is in the name="n" input once submitted via the form.

if you want to see the information that is being passed to the **submit.php** file in the url then you need to change the HTML to use a `get` method for the form instead of the `post` that it currently uses

Comment: Thanks. but how i get the data also in url for eg. if i submit Example Text in field it render in url www.example.com/?n=Example-Text

Comment: To get the data in the URL you have to change the form method to be a get method

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="post" action="/submit.php">
<div class="enter-name">
    <input class="animated pulse infinite" type="name" required="" maxlength="50" name="n" placeholder="Enter Your Text Here">
    <button class="btn" type="submit"><span>></span> Go</button>
</div>
</form>
```

You have to set get method instead of post,
get passes parameters to url, is called urlencodded,

```
<form method="get" action="/submit.php">
```

Comment: Thanks. but how i get the data also in url for eg. if i submit Example Text in field it render in url www.example.com/?n=Example-Text

Comment: You can get by using get or request like,
$_GET['n']; or $_REQUEST['n'];